# String permutation

Tags: permutation, string-manipulation

I have a string "abcd". Is there any way in Mathematica such that when I apply some exchange operator $P^{ab}$ it gives me string "bacd"?

Edit:

After reading answers I felt like I did not ask my question properly.

So, I would like to have something such that I can apply multiple permutations eventually. For example:

$P^{xy}P^{xa}P^{ya}$"xya"="ayx"

$P^{ya}P^{xa}P^{xy}$"xya"="ayx"

and so on.

I am still confused as to how to implement these because the answers sort of do S[1]<>S[2] to change specific ones. Is there a way I can implement these?

Comment: It is much easier to manipulate lists, such as  `{1,2,3,4}`. You can convert them to strings as desired.

Comment: What do you want $P^{ya}$"yxa" to return? Should it be "yxa" or "axy"?

Comment: @CarlWoll I would $P^{ya}$"yxa" to return "axy". For this purpose, I would like to not differentiate between $P^{ya}$ and the inverse $P^{ay}$.

Comment: My answer returns "axy", while the accepted answer returns "yxa". This is why I asked.

Comment: @CarlWoll it was indeed a mistake; I wanted to accept your solution but accidentally did a different one. I really liked your answer. It is amazingly done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`StringReplace`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace):

```
StringReplace[StartOfString~~s1_~~s2_ :> s2 <> s1] @ "abcd"
```

> "bacd"

**Update**

For your updated question you could do:

```
p[s_String /; StringLength[s]==2] := With[{x=StringPart[s,1],y=StringPart[s,2]},
    StringReplace[{x->y,y->x}]
]
```

Examples:

```
p["xy"] @ p["xa"] @ p["ya"] @ "xya"
p["ya"] @ p["xa"] @ p["xy"] @ "xya"
```

> "ayx"

> "ayx"

Comment: Thank you so much. This is beautiful.

Answer (score 7):

**Update:** For the updated version of OP:

```
strngRvrs = RightComposition @@ (StringReplace[# -> StringReverse@#] & /@ {##}) &;
```

**Examples:**

```
strngRvrs["xy"]@"xya"
```

> ```
> "yxa"
> ```

```
strngRvrs["xy", "xa", "ya"]@"xya"
```

> ```
> "ayx"
> ```

```
strngRvrs["ya", "xa", "xy"]@"xya"
```

> ```
> "ayx"
> ```

```
strngRvrs["cd", "cef", "bd"]@"abcdefgh"
```

> ```
> "adbfecgh"
> ```

**Original answer:**

**1.** You can combine [`StringJoin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html) + [`StringTakeDrop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTakeDrop.html) + [`StringReverse`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReverse.html)  as follows:

```
ClearAll[stringShuffle1]
stringShuffle1 = StringJoin[StringReverse @ #, #2] & @@ StringTakeDrop @ ## &;

stringShuffle1["abcd", 2]
```

> ```
> "bacd"
> ```

```
stringShuffle1["abcd", 3]
```

> ```
> "cbad"
> ```

```
stringShuffle1["abcdefghij", 5]
```

> ```
> "edcbafghij"
> ```

**2.** `StringJoin` + `Characters` + `Permute`

```
ClearAll[stringShuffle2]
stringShuffle2 = StringJoin @ Permute[Characters @ #, Reverse @ Range @ #2] &;

stringShuffle2["abcd", 2]
```

> ```
> "bacd"
> ```

```
stringShuffle2["abcdefghij", 2]
```

> ```
> "bacdefghij"
> ```

```
stringShuffle2["abcdefghij", 4]
```

> ```
> "dcbaefghij"
> ```

**3.** `StringJoin` + `Characters` + `PermutationList`

```
ClearAll[stringShuffle3]
stringShuffle3 = StringJoin @
    Characters[#][[PermutationList[Reverse@Range@#2, StringLength@#]]] &;

stringShuffle3["abcd", 2]
```

> ```
> "bacd"
> ```

```
stringShuffle3["abcdefghij", 2]
```

> ```
> "bacdefghij"
> ```

```
stringShuffle3["abcdefghij", 4]
```

> ```
> "dcbaefghij"
> ```

**4.** Alternatively, use `StringReplace` and `StringReverse` to define an operator:

```
ClearAll[stringShuffle4]
stringShuffle4 = StringReplace[StartOfString ~~ # -> StringReverse @ #] &;

stringShuffle4["ab"] @ "abcdefghij"
```

> ```
> "bacdefghij"
> ```

```
stringShuffle4["abcd"] @ "abcdefghij"
```

> ```
> "dcbaefghij"
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Taking a hint from @yarchik's comment:

Break the string `s` down into characters, TakeDrop the first N characters; and then reverse the first list.

```
reverseFirstN[s_String, n_Integer ] := Module[{t, u},
  {t, u} = TakeDrop[Characters[s], n];
  StringJoin[Reverse[t], u]
  ]
```

Test:

```
Table[reverseFirstN["abcdefghijkl", n], {n, 1, 10}] // TableForm
```

[image]

**Edit:** OR maybe you want the specified substrings to swap places:

```
Pab[s_String, a_String, b_String] := Module[{},
  StringReplace[s, {a -> b, b -> a}]
  ]

Pab["abcdabcd", "a", "b"]
```

> "bacdbacd"

```
Pab["abracadabra xoxo", "ab", "x"]
```

> xracadxra aboabo

Answer (score 3):

There's [`ResourceFunction["StringFunction"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/StringFunction/) in the WFR. This gets you something resembling your operator form:

```
perm[s_] := {s[[2]], s[[1]], Sequence @@ s[[3 ;;]]}

p = ResourceFunction["StringFunction"][perm]

p["abcd"] (* bacd *)
p["uvxyzw"] (* vuxyzw *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Permute` and `Cycles`:

```
 p[a_,b_]:=With[{x=StringSplit[#,""], as=ToString[a],bs=ToString[b]},
    StringJoin@Permute[x,Cycles[{Flatten[{Position[x,as],Position[x,bs]}]}]]]&

 pf[list_]:=FoldList[p[Sequence@@#2][#1]&,#,list]&
```

Examples

```
p[x,y]@p[x,a]@p[y,a]@"xya" (* ayx *)
p[y,a]@p[x,a]@p[x,y]@"xya" (* ayx *)
p[c,d]@p[a,b]@"abcd" (* badc *) 

pf[{{x,y},{x,a},{y,a}}]@"xya"
(* {xya, yxa, yax, ayx} *) 

pf[{{a,b},{c,d}}]@"abcd"
(* {abcd, bacd, badc} *)
```

Extending:

```
 p[a_,b_,c_]:=With[{x=StringSplit[#,""], as=ToString[a],bs=ToString[b],cs=ToString[c]},
  StringJoin@Permute[x,
    Cycles[{Flatten[{Position[x,as],Position[x,bs],Position[x,cs]}]}]]]&
```

Examples

```
p[d,a]@p[c,a,d]@"abcd" (* cbad *)

pf[{{c,a,d},{d,a}}]@"abcd"
(* {abcd, cbda, cbad} *)
```

Original Answer:

```
Permute[StringSplit["abcd",""], Cycles[{{1, 2}}]]//StringJoin
(* bacd *)
```